# How to return all the streams at once from a gulp task with multiple source files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

The gulp task I wrote breaks the runSequence in my main gulp task. It has to run in between other tasks, like this:

```
runSequence(
...
':build:prod:staticIndex',
':build:prod:typeDocToMD', // << this is my task
':build:prod:staticDocumentation',
...etc
```

And the task after it never gets executed. Which makes me think that my task doesn't return a single stream or does it incorrectly.

Here is how my task looks:

```
gulp.task(':build:prod:typeDocToMD', (done: any) => {
let taskNum: number = 0;
  let streams = [];
  let filesPath = [
    path.join(__CONFIG.TMPL_DOCS_PATH, '**/*.md')
  ];
  glob(filesPath.toString(), function (er, files) {
    taskNum = files.length - 1;
    files.forEach((filename) => {
      let stream = gulp.src(filename)
        .pipe(addTypedoc()) // << this is the custom plugin I wrote
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
          return file.base;
        }));
      stream.on('end', () => {
        streams.push(stream);
        if (streams.length === taskNum) {
          gUtil.log('the end!');
          return merge(streams);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

So I used glob to recursively get all md files from the folder. And I used [merge-stream](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md) to combine all streams together and return a single one.

I get the 'the end!' message logged but gulp never gets to the next task after that.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not familiar with `merge-stream`, but you are passing an array of streams to it. Did you try `return merge(...streams)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, David! It didn't help, but I found the solution to my issue (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just found a solution to this, and it's ridiculously simple: to use the task's callback argument like this:

```
if (streams.length === taskNum) {
  gUtil.log('the end!');
  done();
}
```

Now it works! And I didn't even have to use merge-stream after all.